# XSLT for Variable Element Name for multiple same elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a piece of XML data with information for multiple persons represented as -

```
<phoneContact>
    <firstName>XXXXX</firstName>
    <middleName>Y</middleName>
    <lastName>ZZZZZ</lastName>
    <phone>1234567890</phone>
</phoneContact>
<phoneContact>
    <firstName>AAAA</firstName>
    <middleName>B</middleName>
    <lastName>CCCCC</lastName>
    <phone>9876543210</phone>
</phoneContact>
```

There may be any number of persons available. I want to transform this into -

```
<phoneContact1>
    <firstName>XXXXX</firstName>
    <middleName>Y</middleName>
    <lastName>ZZZZZ</lastName>
    <phone>1234567890</phone>
</phoneContact1>
<phoneContact2>
    <firstName>AAAA</firstName>
    <middleName>B</middleName>
    <lastName>CCCCC</lastName>
    <phone>9876543210</phone>
</phoneContact2>
```

.. and so forth. How do I construct an XSL for-each code that creates multiple such different element names ?

Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? It's not a good structure to have, as it makes it very difficult to select all phoneContacts for processing. Normally, you would use an *attribute* to distinguish an element from its siblings of same name.

Comment: Agreed.  Your requested output XML form is a much poorer design than your input XML.  What's your bigger picture goal?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Agree, that is a better structure. But I want to do this transform for another implementation downstream, where a DB table will have one record per person with the possibility of having multiple phone numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop over the `phoneContact` elements you can use `<xsl:element>` and the the position function to create your numbered `phoneContacts`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="phoneContact"> 
    <xsl:element name="phoneContact{position()}">
     ...
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: And that worked perfectly, kind Sir. THANK YOU. Here is what I implemented finally -

`<xsl:for-each select="phoneContact">
    <xsl:element name="phoneContact{position()}">
        <firstName><xsl:value-of select="firstName"/></firstName>
        <middleName><xsl:value-of select="middleName"/></middleName>
        <lastName><xsl:value-of select="lastName"/></lastName>
        <phone><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></phone>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>`

Answer (score 0):

we can implement using identity function as below

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/a/phoneContact">
<xsl:element name="phoneContact{position()}">

  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```